# How to Draw/plot or identify in GoogleMaps with below PointData

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps-api, india

How to Draw/plot or identify in GoogleMaps with below PointData? Below are the points generated from spatial cadastre software.

PointName   Xpos    Ypos

_1  341.0926    527.9615

_10 669.1454    527.9615

_2  426.6714    527.9615

_3  450.4432    527.9615

_4  455.1976    527.9615

_5  474.2152    527.9615

_6  547.9084    527.9615

_7  552.6628    527.9615

_8  583.5662    527.9615

_9  612.0926    527.9615

10  669.1454    1026.984

11  797.514 527.9615

13  450.4432    100.2282

14  341.0924    955.6949

15  669.1236    1026.984

16  612.0926    1212.335

17  583.5662    1240.851

18  204 527.9615

2   426.6712    1155.304

4   455.1978    1126.789

5   474.2152    775.0966

6   547.9084    1031.737

7   552.6628    879.6536

8   583.5662    879.6536

9   612.0926    1026.984

Comment: What have you tried, what happened when you did, and what do you want should happen? Could you elaborate on your question to include all relevant info?

Comment: we considered Xpos and Ypos as Latitude and Longtitude and tried plotting in map. For an e.g. Lat Lon 34 degrees (1.0926) minutes, 52 degrees (7.9615) minutes The above is plotting somewhere in Iran, expectation is all the above points should draw a polygon and plot in somewhere in India(Southern Region).

Comment: Can you add where on the Earth your data should be?

Comment: It should be ploted in India andhrapradesh

Comment: Data is collected in Zone IIIA

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE, all of you! It's best if you provide as much relevant info as possible *in the question* itself. Please edit all the new info into the Q via the **edit** "button" (between share and flag), and remove "below" from the title.

Answer (score 2):

I think the data is rather in meters in a projected local CRS.

It might be necessary to add a high number constant to get the full coordinates needed for reprojection to WGS84.

For India, a set of local coordinate systems has been established, see https://deeppradhan.heliohost.org/gis/indian-grid

[image]

You have to know in which zone your data is collected.

It might as well be that a UTM coordinate system is used, with the first columns of both coordinates been stripped off.

---

**EDIT**

If you have no access to the full coordinates, sample lat/lon coordinates of some of your points grabbed from Google Satellite images or a handheld GPS unit might help also.

Comment: This may be a good answer, but, should you be providing it before the question is cleaned up? Just wondering...

Comment: I wanted to push the question in a better direction than degree-minute-second-guessing. But it seems to be a bit difficult...

Comment: Great term: "degree-minute-second-guessing"!