# How can i figure out to convert this points to latlong?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinate-system, google

I got below data in sql server, Learned that data is collected under zone IIIa considering Lambert Conformal conic projection in India. The data is generated from Spatial Cadastre Software. Also learned that XPos and YPos units are in meters.

Expectation: All the below data combined should draw a polygon in google maps. 
Please guide us to convert this points to latlons or any suggestion on how to draw polygon in google maps. It should be plotted in India-AndhraPradesh(State)-Karimnagar(Dist)-Peddapur(Village)

```
PointName   Xpos    Ypos
_0  192         388.6016
_1  189.7742    409.8918
_10 299.5876    382.3074
_11 329.6552    355.2643
_13 334.9612    350.492
_14 373.8721    315.4951
_15 396.8649    294.8151
_16 403.9396    288.452
_17 467.6119    231.1844
_19 536.5903    169.1445
_21 375.0864    452.0209
_3  198.4302    327.0963
_4  202.1399    291.6124
_6  210.3013    213.548
_7  210.7959    208.8169
```

Comment: related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91995/how-to-draw-plot-or-identify-in-googlemaps-with-below-pointdata and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92941/how-to-identify-in-googlemaps-with-below-data

Answer (score 1):

With only three digits before the decimal point it is impossible to do any reprojection.

This is the Karimnagar district and the Zone IIIa grid:

[image]

You need the full coordinates for reprojection.

The village of Peddapur is too small to find it on Openstreetmap. Geonames finds a village of that name, but Northwest of Hyderabad.

Comment: If you have no access to the full coordinates, sample lat/lon coordinates of some of your points grabbed from Google Satellite images or a handheld GPS unit might help also.